# Regex, extract text between two known and unknown values

Tags: c#, regex

I have a problem about how to extract string between two string start with known string plus any unknown string in C#. My question may be confusing. Here's the problem.

> This is the words start with "known_value_1"`unknown-here`"The words I want to extract"`unknown-here`"known_value_2"

So, the two known values and the words I want to extract is inside the double quotes. The problem is, before and after the words to extract are unknown values but with no double quotes.

This doesn't work

```
string value = Regex.Match(input, "\"known_value_1\" \"(.*?)\" \"known_value_2\"").Groups[1].Value;
```

I have no idea about before and after `\"(.*?)\"` to be `unkonwn\"(.*?)\"unkonwn`. The unknown value is not in double quote.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I believe if the unknown-pattern is not known, anything can happen with the extractor and thus may render the regex useless under some special cases...

Comment: @Ian No, because the words to extract is inside double qoutes.

Comment: Sorry, I read again your question. You are right

Comment: @Ian As I said above, the unkown does not contain double quotes.

Comment: A useful online regex tool would be helpful: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rP3sE2/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a non-greedy match anything - `.*?` as unknown.

```
string value = Regex.Match(input, "\"known_value_1\".*?\"(.*?)\".*?\"known_value_2\"").Groups[1].Value;
```